# Link general method to delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, reflection.emit

I want to be able to link a method to all types of delegates. I'm trying to do this with `refelection.emit` and link a dynamic method with the footprint of the delagate, add this to the delegate and let this dynamic method call a general function with all the parameters. but i hope there is an easyer way to do this.

(I have not included the `reflection.emit` code becouse that is not what i want help with, and that is still a raw try)

This is an example of result that i want to get:

```
public class FooClass
    {
        public delegate string MyFirstDelegate(string input1, string input2);
        public delegate int MySecondDelegate(int input1, string input2, short input3);

        public static MyFirstDelegate firstDelegate = null;
        public static MySecondDelegate SecondDelegate = null;

        private static string FirstMethod(string input1, string input2)
        {
            return input1 + input2;
        }

        private static int SecondMethod(int input1, string input2, short input3)
        {
            return input1 + Convert.ToInt32(input2) + input3;
        }

        private static object ThirdMethod(params object[] inputs)
        {
            //do some magic and return result
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            firstDelegate = FirstMethod;
            SecondDelegate = SecondMethod;

            string result = firstDelegate("1", "2");
            int result2 = SecondDelegate(1, "3", 3);

            //obviously this does not work, but is there a way to link this method to the delegate?
            firstDelegate = ThirdMethod;    
            SecondDelegate = ThirdMethod;

            string result3 = firstDelegate("1", "2");
            int result4 = SecondDelegate(1, "3", 3);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To link method to all types of delegate you can make helper method using `Expression` like this:

```
private static TTarget ConvertDelegate<TTarget>(MethodInfo source)
{
    var targetMethod = typeof(TTarget).GetMethod("Invoke");
    var parameters = targetMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name)).ToArray();
    var methodCall = Expression.Call(source, Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), parameters));
    var delegateExpression = Expression.Lambda<TTarget>(Expression.TypeAs(methodCall, targetMethod.ReturnType), parameters);
    return delegateExpression.Compile();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var methodInfo= typeof(FooClass).GetMethod(nameof(ThirdMethod), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
firstDelegate = ConvertDelegate<MyFirstDelegate>(methodInfo);
```

I've also created helper methods to get `MethodInfo` from method name:

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T>(string methodName)
{
    return typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
}

private static TTarget ConvertDelegate<TTarget, TSource>(string sourceMethodName)
{
    return ConvertDelegate<TTarget>(GetMethodInfo<TSource>(sourceMethodName));
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
firstDelegate = ConvertDelegate<MyFirstDelegate, FooClass>(nameof(ThirdMethod));
```

Don't forgett that `ConvertDelegate` will only wrap method with signature `object Name(object[] inputs)`, and if you need to wrap only one method you can save `MethodInfo` in some local value and don't pass as parameter every time.